# JavaScript escape characters coming from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having the simple script as follows,

```
<?php

$actionbutton = '<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href=\'/backoffice_dev.php/currency/edit/EUR\';" value="Edit">';
$tr = '<tr><td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["id"].'</td>
<td><div class="led on"></div></td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["symbol"].'</td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["symbolhtml"].'</td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["usdrate"].'</td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["eurrate"].'</td>
<td>'.$actionbutton.'</td></tr>';

?>

<script>
    var tr = "<?php echo $tr ?>";
    console.log(tr);
</script>
```

But it is throwing a error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL " in chrome. Note that there is no special characters in any of the values coming from PHP. I'm using prototype JS in this page. Is it causing this problem? Because i don't have any knowledge on that.

And how to append this to a table without using `insertRow` and `insertCell` functions? Please help guys..

Comment: how about `echo $tr;` ?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña echo prints correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that there is no special characters in any of the values coming from PHP.

You have literal new lines (which are not allowed in JS string literals). As dhidy points out, you also have unescaped `"` characters in the data and are delimiting the JS string with `"` characters.

Use `json_encode` to turn a PHP string into a (suitably escaped) JavaScript string literal. Note that will generate the quote characters around the data so you shouldn't add them separately.

```
var tr = <?php echo json_encode($tr); ?>;
```

Comment: Great! But the php should print inside double quotes also right? What could be the reason that it didn't work before?

Comment: As I said in the answer, `json_encode` adds escape characters to the data.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of 2 reasons

a) New line character in javascript in consider as statement terminator, wheras not in php

Hence your code echo out

```
        <script>
          var tr = "<tr><td></td>
        <td><div class="led on"></div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/backoffice_dev.php/currency/edit/EUR';" value="Edit"></td></tr>";
            console.log(tr);
        </script>
```

Which is error

b) there is not proper enclosing of '," character ,user escape sequence to do that as show below

```
        <?php

        $actionbutton = '<input type=\'button\' onclick=\'document.location.href=\'/backoffice_dev.php/currency/edit/EUR\';\' value=\'Edit\'>';
        $tr .= '<tr><td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["id"].'</td>';
        $tr .= '<td><div class=\'led on\'></div></td>';
        $tr .= '<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["symbol"].'</td>';
        $tr .= '<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["symbolhtml"].'</td>';
        $tr .= '<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["usdrate"].'</td>';
        $tr .= '<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["eurrate"].'</td>';
        $tr .= '<td>'.$actionbutton.'</td></tr>';

        ?>

        <script>
            var tr = "<?php echo $tr ;?>";
            console.log(tr);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use double quote HTML in your php script, so you have to use single quote in your js.

```
<script>
    var tr = '<?php echo $tr ?>';
    console.log(tr);
</script>
```

**error example**

```
<script>

   <?php $tr = '"' ?>

   var tr = "<?php echo $tr ?>";

   console.log(tr);

</script>
```

`$tr` will be error because `var tr = """;`

Comment: It is true that there are also `"` characters in the string which will cause the problem (although that is fixed by my solution too) but your approach won't solve the additional problem of the new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes in your PHP strings since you're wrapping them in double quotes in your JavaScript. You also need to get rid of the new lines.